# Will there be some pre-change notification ?

Tags: swift, realm

I have some problems integrating the realm database into my Swift 3.1 iOS App.

to update und manage the sections from a grouped UITableView it would be nice to be notified before each change on the realm is commited. 
Or in other words, I need a reference to deleted objects to calculate the  indexPath to delete.

Is there a way or workaround to get this ?

Greetings Peter

Answer (score 1):

You can use Collection Notifications for that. Please check out the docs at https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collection-notifications.

Comment: Your right this works well in a simple table with only one section.  But imagine some more complex table view where a collection of objects is sorted and arranged in multiple sections. Another user deletes an object and my notification Handler will execute with the deleted index in the unsorted and ungrouped array. I have no way calculating the right indexPath without comparing the sorted objects in my tableView  with the deleted object. So I need a reference to the delete object or a notification before it will be deleted.

Comment: Well in general case your table view should be in sync with your models and notification handler receives correct index. You will probably find  https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4506 useful in terms of managing sections in tableview backed by Realm.